# Can't resolve a single site from inside virtual boxed guest Ubuntu 14.04 (64bit)

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, vagrant, ubuntu-14.04

Strangely, I can access from guest OS all sites, but **bitbucket.org**, while can access it from host OS.

Any idea, why?

pinging:

```
vagrant@cabinet:~/app$ ping google.com
PING google.com (173.194.32.136) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 173.194.32.136: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=2.68 ms
64 bytes from 173.194.32.136: icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=4.89 ms
64 bytes from 173.194.32.136: icmp_seq=3 ttl=63 time=6.51 ms
64 bytes from 173.194.32.136: icmp_seq=4 ttl=63 time=6.14 ms
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3011ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 2.689/5.059/6.513/1.495 ms
vagrant@cabinet:~/app$ ping superuser.com
PING superuser.com (198.252.206.16) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from stackoverflow.com (198.252.206.16): icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=143 ms
64 bytes from stackoverflow.com (198.252.206.16): icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=137 ms
64 bytes from stackoverflow.com (198.252.206.16): icmp_seq=3 ttl=63 time=139 ms
^C
--- superuser.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2005ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 137.228/140.307/143.958/2.810 ms
vagrant@cabinet:~/app$ ping bitbucket.org
ping: unknown host bitbucket.org
```

looking up:

```
vagrant@cabinet:~/app$ nslookup bitbucket.org
Server:         10.0.2.3
Address:        10.0.2.3#53

** server can't find bitbucket.org: SERVFAIL

vagrant@cabinet:~/app$ nslookup google.com
Server:         10.0.2.3
Address:        10.0.2.3#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 173.194.32.129
Name:   google.com
Address: 173.194.32.137
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not able to resolve bitbucket.org then most likely it is your DNS server at fault. To verify the same just query from another DNS server like this:

```
nslookup bitbucket.org 8.8.8.8
```